# Adjust javascript regex to filter vars from url

Tags: javascript, regex

So i currently have this:

```
matches = val.match(/kickstarter\/projects(.*?)/);
```

To match the info after a kickstarters project url like this for example:

```
http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/defiant/hand-of-fate-a-card-game-that-comes-to-life?ref=home_spotlight
```

So with that code it gives me:

```
/defiant/hand-of-fate-a-card-game-that-comes-to-life?ref=home_spotlight
```

I want it to remove anything where there is a ? including that character itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove stuff by using the `match` function. But you surely can use

```
val.replace(/\?.*$/, '')
```

to replace anything from a question mark to the end by an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

I would actually do something like

`newstr = str.split("?")[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `[^?]` instead of `.` in your re:

```
> url.match(/kickstarter\.com\/projects([^?]+)/)[1]
"/defiant/hand-of-fate-a-card-game-that-comes-to-life"
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want is:

```
matches = val.match(/kickstarter.com\/projects([^?]*)/)
```